# PHP - Getting text from a text file and using them in a "loop"!

Tags: php, function, loops, foreach, genfromtxt

Im new to php, and i really need some help with this script. I have a text file with names(serverlist.txt). The first line of code gets these names. I want it to get one name, put it in to the last bit of code(), Then repeat the process untill there are no lines of text in the serverlist.txt.

Please help me.

```
    <?php 
$file = 'serverlist.txt';
$content = "";
if($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) {
    while(!feof($handle)) {
        $content .= fgets($handle);
            foreach($content as $cont) {
            }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}



?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://minecraft.net/skin/<?php 


echo $cont; ?>.png" alt="">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then what is the result of your code..any error? no result? something?

Comment: My code gives out many names inside one img tag, i want 1 name inside many img tags. So i guess the foreach is my error, beacuse i dont know how to use it to "display" on name at the time and then repeat the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the output of the server names in a variable and then output them in your HTML body.

```
<?php 
  $file = 'serverlist.txt';
  $servers = '';
  if ($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
      $content = trim(fgets($handle));
      $names = explode(' ', $content);
      foreach ($names as $name) {
        $servers .= '<img src="http://minecraft.net/skin/' . $name. '.png" alt="">';
      }
    }
   fclose($handle);
  }
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo $servers; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for this. This does not work, but i like this idea. The problem is that this gives me all the names in the file at the same time inside the image. Now it gives me many names inside 1 image, i want 1 name inside many images.

Comment: @user2176480 - Could you please post an example of how your data file **serverlist.txt** is formatted? It's hard to know how to deal with the data if we don't know how it is formatted. In other words, is it separated by commas? Multiple lines? etc.

Comment: Its only separated by a no break space and lookes like this: 
name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6

Comment: @user2176480 - Thanks for the info :). I have revised my answer to parse the names one at a time.

Comment: This still gives out one picture with all the names inside the $name 
=/

Comment: If you could take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447913/php-if-while-and-or-img-resizing-error I would be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$content = array ();

$fd = fopen ('serverlist.txt', 'r');
while ($line = trim (fgets ($fd)))
{
    $content [] = $line;
}
fclose ($fd);
?>

<html>
  <body>
    <? foreach ($content as $cont) { ?>
      <img src="http://minecraft.net/skin/<?= $cont ?>.png">
    <? } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. This does not work. It gives me all the text inside the txt at the same time inside the img tag. I want 1 name for each of the img tags.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    $file = 'serverlist.txt';
    $content = "";

    if($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) {
        while(!feof($handle)) {
            $content .= fgets($handle);
            foreach($content as $cont) {
                echo '<img src="http://minecraft.net/skin/'.$cont.'.png" alt="">';
            }
        }
    fclose($handle);
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like all you are trying to do, is use $cont to modify an img src.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work. I see now how i can use php inside a <img>, but the main problem is that with this result i would get one image with many name inside it, but i want many images with one name inside them.