# PHP if/while and or img resizing error

Tags: php, html, while-loop, if-statement

coders. Im very new to php, so my code is prob as wrong as it gets.
Im loading plain text from a txt file and useing that to load pictures from a website. (Thanks to this forum for helping me with that). Now im having problems with resizing those photos. First of all, i dont think i got the if statement right on the last 2. and i dont really know how to use "while", and if i even have to use it.

Can you look over the code and see if you see any mistakes? Thank you.

In the first (if) section i made the text in the txt file to images. Now i want to resize all those images. In the second (if) im trying to call all those images to be resized. In the third (if) im trying to call all those resized images so i can echo them in the last bit of code.

```
<?php

$file = 'serverlist.txt';
$servers = '';
if ($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $content = trim(fgets($handle));
        $names = explode(' ', $content);
        foreach ($names as $name) {
            $servers .= '<img src="http://minecraft.net/skin/' . $name . '.png" alt="">';
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {

}
if $file == 'serverlist.txt' {
    $fullimages = explode($servers);
    foreach ($fullimages as $_fullimages) {
        $face = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $imgwidth = 200;
        $imgheight = 200;
        imagecopyresized($face, $_fullimages, 0, 0, 8, 8, $width, $height, 8, 8);
        imagecopyresized($face, $_fullimages, 0, 0, 40, 8, $width, $height, 8, 8);
    }
} else {

}
if $file = 'serverlist.txt' {
    $displayimages = explode($_fullimages);
    foreach ($displayimages as $_displayimages) {

    }
} else {

}
echo $_displayimages;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asigned the values in every `if` statement you should use `==` instead of single `=`

```
<?php

    $file = 'serverlist.txt';
    $servers = '';
    if ($handle == fopen($file, 'r')) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $content = trim(fgets($handle));
            $names = explode(' ', $content);
            foreach ($names as $name) {
                $servers .= '<img src="http://minecraft.net/skin/' . $name . '.png" alt="">';
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } else {

    }
    if ($file == 'serverlist.txt') {
        $fullimages = explode($servers);
        foreach ($fullimages as $_fullimages) {
            $face = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
            $imgwidth = 200;
            $imgheight = 200;
            imagecopyresized($face, $_fullimages, 0, 0, 8, 8, $width, $height, 8, 8);
            imagecopyresized($face, $_fullimages, 0, 0, 40, 8, $width, $height, 8, 8);
        }
    } else {

    }
    if ($file == 'serverlist.txt') {
        $displayimages = explode($_fullimages);
        foreach ($displayimages as $_displayimages) {

        }
    } else {

    }
    echo $_displayimages;
    ?>
```

Comment: Now the page loads. Thank you. But i dont get any content. If i remove everything after the first else{} the images loads.

Comment: can you explain what you trying to do?

Comment: In the first if section i made the text in the txt file to images. Now i want to resize all those images. In the second if im trying to call all those images to be resized. In the third if im trying to call all those resized images so i can echo them in the last bit of code.

Comment: then you can give like this <img src="http://minecraft.net/skin/' . $name . '.png" alt="" style="width:100px;height:100px;"> so that you can omit the two steps

Comment: I would do that, but i also need to crop the image.